How do i see the same options when right clicking multiple files as for single?
For example, I'm using ecmo unlockit to delete files, when I right click a single file/folder, there is an option in the context menu to delete it. When I click more then one file/folder, there is no such option. How can I add it back for that situation?

It may be meaningless, if the application can only unlock one file at a time. However, if it can do so, first uninstall the application, then reinstall it -- that should re-register it. Or try an alternative, such as LockHunter.
